# Get past 6 months data from a table based on the recent date present in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I have a database table which is named as `table` and there is a column `Col` which is present in `table` with datatype `varchar`. Column `Col` contains dates in the format `MMM-YY`.
For example `Col` has values as :

| Col |
| --- |
| DEC-21 |
| NOV-21 |
| SEP-20 |
| OCT-19 |
| DEC-21 |

As, we can see data can be duplicated like DEC-21. I want to extract last 6 months data based on the recent month present in `Col`. For example, If the DEC-21 is the most recent date(consider, day is not present) and so, I want data from DEC-21 to JUN-21 i.e. 12-21 to 06-21 if we map DEC to 12 and JUN to 06. This    `Table` has many columns and one of the columns is `Col` which I mentioned above and I have to extract data based on the column `Col` by using SQL query.

I have written a query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CAST(RIGHT(Col,4) AS INT) Between 2020 and 2021
```

But here I get data between 2020 and 2021. So, By doing some modification in the above query or Is there any other way to get the past 6 months data from the recent date which is in `MMM-YYYY` format from `Col` column.
I was writing code in R and I was using `dbGetQuery()` where I have to pass the SQL query. I have already done this thing after storing it in a dataframe but is there any way to do it directly by sql query ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe adding a new column with a real datetime type based on the entries in col will help. You could set the Date to the first of month.

Comment: Yes, it may help but I can't add/drop columns in the table. Is there any way to do it by using "select" only ?

Comment: Of course you can: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eZuNMDpstRRqKWWppxkTLy/0

Comment: Yes, I can see the output but when I run it in RStudio by passing this sql query in dbGetQuery() as a string, it shows error as "Incorrect syntax near '|' ". I am using Microsoft SQL Server. Is the syntax different in case of MSSQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        convert(date, '01-' + dt, 105) as converted_dt,
        max(convert(date, '01-' + dt, 105)) over () as last_converted_dt
    from T
)
select * from data
where converted_dt >= dateadd(month, -6, last_converted_dt);
```

The 105 comes from the list of date formats which can be found in the documentation for `cast/convert`. SQL Server can convert strings like `Apr 2021` so a cast like below might also work (if you actually have four-digit years) but it's best to be explicit about the format as I did above.

```
cast(replace(dt, '-', ' ' as date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am running the code in RStudio and when I pass the above sql query  in dbGetQuery() function as a string, I get the error as "Incorrect syntax near '105'."  after replacing "dt" with column name "Col" and "T" with table name "table". I am using MSSQL. May be I am doing some mistake. Could you please tell me the mistake and if possible, could you please tell me the significance of number "105" here ?

Comment: Small syntax error corrected above. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df3c4/1

Comment: Thanks!. Now, it is not showing any error but it is taking too much time. When I do "select * from table" then it takes 2 minutes but when I run the above code, it already has taken 10 minutes and still running. "table" has ~4.6 million rows. Is there any way to optimize the above code ? @shawnt00

Comment: That's why it's important to store it as a date. If not that then maybe index as a computed column / filtered index. Possibly creating a view is a consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

SELECT * FROM table  where CONVERT(DATE,'01-'+Col) BETWEEN '01-Jun-2021' and '31-Dec-2021'

Comment: Thank you but it is between some specific dates. I wanted past 6 months data from recent date in a column. I can get it after sorting column values in descending order by using "order by" and get the first value and from this value, I can find the last 6 months data but I am unable to write in single sql query with "select" statement.